# Page Build Error from static /docs folder on Github Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a static site, built **locally** by Jekyll, in a `/docs` folder inside the master branch of my repo, and have set my GH Pages settings to serve from that folder.

However, I keep getting `Your site is having problems building: Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-build-failures.`

Some notes:

- The repo itself is a Jekyll project, however, as I am using a private submodule GH Pages won't serve this as a Jekyll site, therefore this is why I have compiled the site locally to `/docs` and set this to be where GH Pages serves from.
- The files in `/docs` are all compiled and just HTML, CSS and JS. No folders or files with `_` preceding.
- I have added `.nojekyll` in both the `/docs` folder and also in the root of the project, just in case.
- The error message above is the only information GitHub is returning; no specific error code.

As far as I can tell, this is just a basic static website and GH should have no problem serving it. The only thing I can think is that it's getting confused by the fact that it's inside a jekyll project, but the only fix I can see for that is `.nojekyll` and that hasn't worked.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm afraid I can't share the repo as it is a private company repo.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer immediately so others may find it useful.

The private submodule breaks the build process, even though the pages site is set to serve from the `/docs` subfolder. Removing the submodule fixes the issue and serves the site as expected.